# _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'jinja2.utils.MissingType'>: it's not found as jinja2.utils.MissingType

Tags: python, jinja2, pickle, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to run a `PythonVirtualenvOperator` within a `dag` in a `gcloud composer` environment but am getting an error while the virtual environment is created. A google search led me to https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/93 but I am not sure I understand where the problem exactly is.

**Environment Details**

Image version: composer-1.4.1-airflow-1.9.0
Python version: 3

**Code**:

```
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator,PythonVirtualenvOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow import models
import traceback
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt

yesterday = dt.combine(dt.today() - datetime.timedelta(1), dt.min.time())

def dummy_func(**kwargs):
    config=kwargs.get('config',False)
    print("1")

default_dag_args = {
    # Setting start date as yesterday starts the DAG immediately when it is
    # detected in the Cloud Storage bucket.
    'start_date':yesterday,
    # To email on failure or retry set 'email' arg to your email and enable
    # emailing here.
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    # If a task fails, retry it once after waiting at least 5 minutes
    'retries': 0,
    #'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'project_id': 'abc'
    #models.Variable.get('gcp_project')
}

try:
  # [START composer_quickstart_schedule]
    DAG=models.DAG(
        'erised_map_dummy', #dag name
        # Continue to run DAG once per day
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        default_args=default_dag_args)
    # [END composer_quickstart_schedule]


    config={"a":1}

    # INITIALIZATION
    # Initializing Configurations variable

    # Read from GCS, Process and Write back to GCS
    Start = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
                    task_id="start_it",
                    python_callable=dummy_func,
                    requirements=["pandas==0.23.4","numpy","dill"],
                    use_dill=True,
                    system_site_packages=False,
                    #op_kwargs={'config':config},
                    provide_context=True,
                    dag=DAG
                    )

    op_end = BashOperator(task_id='Finished', bash_command='echo Success!', dag=DAG)

    Start >> op_end

except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
    raise(e)
# [END composer_quickstart]
```

**Error:**
`_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'jinja2.utils.MissingType'>: it's not found as jinja2.utils.MissingType`

**Traceback Stack:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 269, in _getattribute
    obj = getattr(obj, subpath)
AttributeError: module 'jinja2.utils' has no attribute 'MissingType'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 918, in save_global
    obj2, parent = _getattribute(module, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 272, in _getattribute
    .format(name, obj))
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'MissingType' on <module 'jinja2.utils' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/utils.py'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 6, in <module>
    exec(compile(open(__file__).read(), __file__, 'exec'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 528, in test
    ti.run(ignore_task_deps=True, ignore_ti_state=True, test_mode=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 1583, in run
    session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 1492, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 89, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 245, in execute_callable
    self._write_args(input_filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 283, in _write_args
    dill.dump(arg_dict, f)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 286, in dump
    pik.dump(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 409, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 781, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 808, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 1377, in save_function
    obj.__dict__), obj=obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 610, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 751, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 605, in save_reduce
    save(cls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 1321, in save_type
    StockPickler.save_global(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 922, in save_global
    (obj, module_name, name))
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'jinja2.utils.MissingType'>: it's not found as jinja2.utils.MissingType
```

Comment: You tried this without using dill too right? Basically dill is saying it can't pickle the jinja2 context you pass into the callable. Setting provide_context kind of adds it to the op_kwargs which is checked for and serialized with either dill or pickle.

Comment: It resolved after I set `provide_context` as `False`. According to documentation `:param provide_context: if set to true, Airflow will pass a set of
        keyword arguments that can be used in your function. This set of
        kwargs correspond exactly to what you can use in your jinja
        templates. For this to work, you need to define **kwargs in your
        function header.` which causes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It resolved after I set `provide_context` as `False`. According to documentation `:param provide_context: if set to true, Airflow will pass a set of keyword arguments that can be used in your function. This set of kwargs correspond exactly to what you can use in your jinja templates. For this to work, you need to define **kwargs in your function header.`which causes the error.